# zend, php session, jquery ajax problem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, internet-explorer-8

Here is what happens to *some* users of IE8 when using the website i am responsible for:

1. person logs in, credentials are verified, zend auth is created. After login, user is redirected to the default page.
2. the default page has 5 ajax request that start on document ready. The ajaxes somehow don't have the php session in the request and result with returning a login form. 2 of these ajaxes return json, 3 return html. zend auth is still available for these requests.

After inspecting the headers and the cookies, headers are proper, PHPSESSID is different.

More on the environment, php 5.2, https on entire website, jquery 1.2.3
The ajax requests are made with .ajax

Can someone please help with some advice?

Comment: Do all of the PHP pages called through Ajax use session_start()?  Do any of them set a session_name()?  Everything is definitely through HTTPS?

Comment: session_start is controlled by zend_session automatically. no session_name used. yes, everything is through https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a more modern version of jQuery? 1.2.3 is almost three years old (a lifetime in jQuery world) and predates IE8 so no testing for IE8 would have been done.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this issue with the first thing I tried.

These parallel ajax requests were too much for ie8 to handle. Removed the ajaxes and the problem was solved. Did not try how many requests ie can actually handle.... 
Still strange how this happened only on some ie8's but anyway, problem solved.

Thanks Kris for the answer, your suggestion would have been the next thing to try... certainly seems reasonable...

Comment: A recent project designed to do 5 or 6 ajax queries on load, was modified by the client to do over 200.  IE8 could still handle it (albeit not very quickly.)